# jQuery Animate works after first click

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to hook up jQuery's animate ability with a bookmark id on a site. When I click on the link, it went to my bookmark id without animation but when I clicked the same link again, the animation works.

```
var TitleNav = React.createClass({
    handleSubmitClick:function()
    {
        $('a').click(function()
        {
            $('html, body').animate(
            {
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });
    },

    render:  function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul className = "nav">
                    <li className = "navworkspace" onClick ={this.handleSubmitClick}><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

I assume it is the way that the components are called since components do not wait on each other. Is there a way to fix this?

Note: I am using React.Js to render my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is your handleSubmitClick function is only binding the click event handler to the link, but not trigger the event. So the first time you click on the link, it does nothing but only bind the event. After that, since the handler is binded, the animation works the 2nd times and so on. you can change the code to

```
var TitleNav = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function()
    {
        $('.nav a').click(function()
        {
            $('html body').animate(
            {
                scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
            }, 500);
            return false;
        });
    },

    render:  function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul className = "nav">
                    <li className = "navworkspace"><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

or you can do this

```
var TitleNav = React.createClass({
    handleSubmitClick: function(e)
    {
        $('html body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop:$(e.target).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;

    },

    render:  function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul className = "nav">
                    <li className = "navworkspace" ><a href="#work" onClick ={this.handleSubmitClick}>Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, your first solution worked and I had a feeling it was suppose to use ComponentWillMount but wasn't sure how the event "click" was going to trigger it. For the second answer you provided it is the same as gapvision and it didn't work, though it sounds like it is suppose to.

Comment: ComponentWillMount  trigger before your component is created in the DOM, so $('a') will return no elements to you.
The second solution doesn't use $('a').click(function(), but calling the animation directly

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, since this is a nice concise answer I will accept it.

Comment: @AnthonyC no offence but the second solution won't work as the `this` is referring to the class itself in this context and not the `a` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thats exactly what this code should do.

On the first click `handleSubmitClick` is called which creates then the click-handler on `a`.

So only the at the second click, a click-handler on `a` is installed and will execute the code. Actually you are creating a new click-handler on `a` on every click.

So basically, just get rid of the additional click-handler for `a` and execute the body of it directly in the `onclick` for the `li`:

```js
    var TitleNav = React.createClass({
    handleSubmitClick:function()
    {
            $('html, body').animate(
            {
                scrollTop: $($.attr(this.refs.link, 'href')).offset().top
            }, 500);
    },

    render:  function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <ul className = "nav">
                    <li className = "navworkspace"><a ref="link" href="#work" onClick ={this.handleSubmitClick}>Work</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Sad to say that it did not work. Once I took out the handler on a, the handleSubmitClick does nothing.

Comment: if you put the `handleSubmitClick` directly on the `a`?

Comment: If what you mean is `<li className = "navworkspace"><a onClick ={this.handleSubmitClick} href="#work">Work</a></li>` then yes I tried that and it did not work. I also copied and pasted your code for quality assurance and it didn't work.

Comment: @LampPost you are right, the thing missing hier is the `this` reference - I changed my code above